# unexpected result with php date function

Tags: php, date

I am getting an unexpected result with my date function. For example

```
    $date = '25-05-2049';
    echo '<p>'.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date)).'</p>'; // Showing 1970-01-01
```

But this is correct

```
    $date = '25-05-2029';
    echo '<p>'.date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date)).'</p>'; // 2029-05-25
```

Why is the first one incorrect?

Comment: Not able to reproduce https://3v4l.org/R1mXK

Comment: Which version of php you are using?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem ?

Comment: @Qirel Run that on eval.in ;-) you'll see what happens.

Comment: @PankajMakwana it's not the version of php that's in question, it's the bit system that's it's running on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 32 bit PHP `strtotime()` can't handle the [2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

> If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format, the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999. See the notes below for possible differences on 32bit systems (possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07).

So either use a 64 bit version of PHP or use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to work with dates.

```
$date = new DateTime('25-05-2049');
echo '<p>'.$date->format('Y-m-d').'</p>';
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/868345)

Comment: Right you are John. I think that eval.in runs on 32-bit https://eval.in/868343 because that's showing as `1970-01-01`.

Comment: Very help full and amazing answer. I tested my php, it is with 32-bit and **DateTime()**  is working.